# Native Android GDB remote debug got SIGILL

Tags: android, native, remote-debugging

Software: Official TI android release (source code package), Jelly bean 4.2.2 for AM335x, (Yes, arago/rowboat/TI developers add modifications to vanilla aosp but not relevant to my question.)

Hardware: am335xevm_sk (a TI dev booard based on AM335x Cortex A8 SOC)

What I do:

1. build the system and using sd card to boot the hardware. Everything works properly.
2. adb pull the init.am335xevm.rc file, comment out the rild service and push it back, reboot the target system. I do this because I want to use cross debugger to remote debug rild.
3. set up the remote debug: adb forward tcp ports. and launch gdbserver on target system, as:

   ```
   root@android:/ # gdbserver localhost:2345 system/bin/rild
   Process system/bin/rild created; pid = 829
   Listening on port 2345
   Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
   ```
4. remote debug rild, as:

   ```
   ma@ma-aspire:~/devkit/JB422$ PATH=$PATH:/home/ma/devkit/JB422/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin
   ma@ma-aspire:~/devkit/JB422$ arm-linux-androideabi-gdb
   GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1-gg2
   Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. Type "show copying"
   and "show warranty" for details.
   This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-android".
   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
   <xxxx://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>. 
   (gdb) file /home/ma/devkit/JB422/out/target/product/am335xevm_sk/symbols/system/bin/rild 
   Reading symbols from /home/ma/devkit/JB422/out/target/product/am335xevm_sk/symbols/system/bin/rild...done.
   (gdb) set sysroot /home/ma/devkit/JB422/out/target/product/am335xevm_sk/symbols
   (gdb) target remote localhost:2345
   Remote debugging using localhost:2345
   __dl__start () at bionic/linker/arch/arm/begin.S:35
   35 mov r0, sp
   (gdb) n
   36 mov r1, #0
   (gdb) n
   37 bl __linker_init
   (gdb) n

   Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
   0x4013a89e in __linker_init (elfdata=0xbee7bae0) at bionic/linker/linker.cpp:2030
   2030 extern "C" unsigned __linker_init(unsigned **elfdata) {
   (gdb) c
   Continuing.

   Program terminated with signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
   The program no longer exists.
   (gdb)
   ```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I am not very familiar with low-level toolchain problem. I googled the problem and it seems very few people encountered the same problem.

I downloaded the aosp source (Android 4.2.2_r1, JDQ39) and compared the prebuilt toolchain and NDK content, no significant difference was found.

I also tried with the latest NDK (r10b). Use the prebuilt toolchain in the NDK to rebuild the whole target system and do the debug, the results are the same.

I also tried to generate the standalone toolchain with platform set to android-17 and android-18, and repeat the above steps, the results are the same.

I also tried to re-built the NDK toolchain and got no difference.

I also tried the newer version of gdbserver (prebuilts in NDK r10b package), and the problem persists.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

but if I use the NDK toolchain to debug a simple hello-world program (with liblog dynamically linked), as proposed in this page:

www dot srombauts dot fr/2011/03/06/standalone-toolchain/

and do the debug, I can step into main(), but after the program exit, the process on target system got a similar SIGILL termination, instead of a normal exit.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I am very confused why this occurs, since many many developers use gdb to debug native code and platform developers at google should also rely on gdb debug heavily. It seems unlikely that the problem arised from a bug in gdb or gdbserver. Perhaps it is related and specific to am335x kernel? Or I missed something important to use gdb? say, target architecture options? Or certain compiler options should be specified for this kind of native debug? I had read quite a few online articles on native remote debug on android carefully and not found anything specifically being pointed out.

I really want to use remote GDB to debug some native program, including ril and some other test cases wrapping HAL libs. Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this isn't an answer but an supplementary to my previous question.

I digged the problem further.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I put a basic helloworld program inside android source tree:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "hello-native", __VA_ARGS__))

void main(void)
{
    printf("Hello Native Printf\n");
    LOGI("Hello Native LOGI");
}
```

with Android.mk file as:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := hello-native
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-native.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Then the debug fails with SIGILL as mentioned in the previous post.

But if I use a standard Makefile (as proposed by Karim Yaghmour in his excellent book Embedded Android, page 140):

```
#Paths and settings

TARGET_PRODUCT = am335xevm_sk
ANDROID_ROOT = /home/ma/devkit/JB422
BIONIC_LIBC = $(ANDROID_ROOT)/bionic/libc
PRODUCT_OUT = $(ANDROID_ROOT)/out/target/product/$(TARGET_PRODUCT)
CROSS_COMPILE = $(ANDROID_ROOT)/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-

# Tool names
AS = $(CROSS_COMPILE)as
AR = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ar
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
CPP = $(CC) -E
LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
NM = $(CROSS_COMPILE)nm
OBJCOPY = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy
OBJDUMP = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objdump
RANLIB = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ranlib
READELF = $(CROSS_COMPILE)readelf
SIZE = $(CROSS_COMPILE)size
STRINGS = $(CROSS_COMPILE)strings
STRIP = $(CROSS_COMPILE)strip

export AS AR CC CPP LD NM OBJCOPY OBJDUMP RANLIB READELF \
SIZE STRINGS STRIP

# Build settings

CFLAGS = -O0 -Wall -fno-short-enums -ggdb

HEADER_OPS = -I$(BIONIC_LIBC)/include \
-I$(BIONIC_LIBC)/arch-arm/include \
-I$(BIONIC_LIBC)/kernel/common \
-I$(BIONIC_LIBC)/kernel/arch-arm \
-I$(ANDROID_ROOT)/system/core/include

LDFLAGS = -nostdlib -Wl,-dynamic-linker,/system/bin/linker \
$(PRODUCT_OUT)/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o \
$(PRODUCT_OUT)/obj/lib/crtend_android.o \
-L$(PRODUCT_OUT)/obj/lib -lc -ldl -llog

# Installation variables
EXEC_NAME = hello-native
INSTALL = install
INSTALL_DIR = $(PRODUCT_OUT)/system/bin

# Files needed for the build
OBJS = hello-native.o

# Make rules
all: hello-native

.c.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADER_OPS) -c $<

hello-native: ${OBJS}
$(CC) -o $(EXEC_NAME) ${OBJS} $(LDFLAGS)

install: hello-native
test -d $(INSTALL_DIR) || $(INSTALL) -d -m 755 $(INSTALL_DIR)
$(INSTALL) -m 755 $(EXEC_NAME) $(INSTALL_DIR)

clean:
rm -f *.o $(EXEC_NAME) core
distclean:
rm -f *~
rm -f *.o $(EXEC_NAME) core
```

Then the program compiles and debug correctly. The only exception is when program exits, if I set sysroot to /out/target/product/am335xevm_sk/symbols, I got and SIGILL, but if I do not set debugger sysroot, the program exits normally.

They works all the same way with different Toolchain and debugger, that from original TI release, that from the original or new version NDK, or that rebuilts from source code in NDK.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Then I tried to compile rild in ARM code, with LOCAL_ARM_MODE set to arm, as:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libdl
endif # arm

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DRIL_SHLIB -O0
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_MODULE:= rild
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Then the program compiles and debug correctly, if I do NOT set sysroot to out/target/product/am335xevm_sk/symbols, otherwise, the debugger can step into linker and crash with SIGILL as previously mentioned.

This at least provide a workaround solution for my need, but I can NOT believe that the Android (ndk) gdb can NOT handle thumb codes? Is there anything I missed for gcc/gdb settings? or some gcc options are modified in Rowboat distro that prevent official gdb tool from working properly?

HELP!

Comment: Hi not an expert by any means but I recommend creating a simple example android app that imports some native code (compiles some native code into a library and then loads it from Java), and then debug it with the ndk-gdb command, in order to see what ndk-gdb does. It sets the solib path to the path containing the native library, but it also pulls some libraries from the device and adds them to the solib path.  I only got my debug working and free of SIGILL's once I started debugging with ndk-gdb (and of course using adb root)